# DateTimeFormat accepting numbers in json request instead of date format

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, jsr

I need to validate date using jsr annotations / spring rest

```
@Email(regexp = ".+@.+\\..+")
private String email;
@NotNull
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

But its accepting below json request

```
{ "email": "eerwer@gmail.com","dateOfBirth": 7,}
```

and its parsing the date as **1970-01-07** (adding 7 days from 1970)

even below annotation is allowing numbers

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

How can I invalidate this request

Comment: Could it be that `dateOfBirth` is part of `@RequestBody` object? Is the controller parameter annotated with `@Valid` there to trigger validation?

Comment: yes @Valid is there and validations are working on date format as well. Only issue is its allowing numbers

Comment: if i pass 7 , its adding 7 ms to the date

Comment: Your annotation is useless. Spring is not parsing the JSON. Your JSON parser (probably Jackson) is. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/blob/master/datetime/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/InstantDeserializer.java. AFAIK, you'll need to use a custom deserializer to forbid numbers to be successfuly parsed.

Comment: spring 5.1.4 RELEASE

Comment: @JB Nizet  then @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z") should have worked right..? but even this is allowing numbers

Comment: Maybe [lenient = Boolean.FALSE](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1733) would change the behavior?

Comment: @yegodm unfortunately this doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: Not sure what is different with your setup. Running `mapper.readValue("{\"dateOfBirth\" : \"7\"}", Person.class)` with jsr310 module on my local produces an exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDate from String "7": Text '7' could not be parsed at index 0...`. The `Person` class has one field `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")        private LocalDate dateOfBirth;`.

Comment: @yegodm please change this  "{\"dateOfBirth\" : \"7\"}" to "{\"dateOfBirth\" : 7}" This validation os working with "7" but not number 7

Comment: With integer the error becomes `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.`. Jackson is of version 2.8.3

Comment: And with Jackson 2.9.8 integer passes without error - something has changed between 2.8.3 -> 2.9.8.

Comment: yes I am using 2.9.8 :-( . Is there any way i can restrict numbers with the request  attributes

Comment: It is all about [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/20).

Comment: yes, it changed the behaviour and there doesn't seem to have any flag to disable this feature.

Comment: If no chance to downgrade to 2.8.x, perhaps custom serializer/desrializer then?

Comment: i think writing custom serializer is better option..  But even then i think it will read the date as 1970-01-07 instead of 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up writing my own deserializer

```
class LocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate> {

protected LocalDateDeserializer(){
    super(LocalDate.class);
}

@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return LocalDate.parse(jp.readValueAs(String.class));

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

Notice that `LocalDateDeserializer` and `LocalDateTimeDeserializer` support internally `leniency` features.

That being said, a clean solution that you can make available through a Bean:

```
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // make sure you added jackson-datatype-jsr310 dependency
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    // option 1
    objectMapper.setDefaultLeniency(FALSE);

    // option 2
    objectMapper.configOverride(LocalDate.class).setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forLeniency(FALSE));
    objectMapper.configOverride(LocalDateTime.class).setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forLeniency(FALSE));


    return objectMapper;
}
```

Another in-place alternative could be:

`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)`

on the field/method itself

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder or with a customizer? I could not find any ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Validate date using jsr notationspring rest.

Add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Entity field like this.

```
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate expireDate;
```

Json request like this.

```
{
    "expireDate" :"2015-01-01"
}
```

Comment: ofcourse this will work. But this will accept numbers as well try { "expireDate" :7 }

Comment: It is not accepting number.Giving error. did you try?

Comment: Can you make sure you tried this { "expireDate" :7 } instead of { "expireDate" :"7" }

Comment: I tried.only  "2015-01-01" is work.Neigher 7 not "7".